# IKVM - Lots of error message while using converted dll in .NET, making application slow

Tags: java, .net, ikvm

I'm using the `ikvm v 7.2.4630.5` for converting my Java JAR project into a `.NET dll`.
Running the ikvm command line tool works fine.
Then I add the created dll (together with all the other IKVM-dll's) as a reference in a new .NET C# project.
I can create the object and call the method but while running it generates 1000's of error lines like:

> 'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'ikvm_dynamic_assembly250870979'.
>
> 'ABC.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ABC.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\ISymWrapper\v4.0_4.0.0.0b03f5f7f11d50a3a\ISymWrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' occurred in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'java.security.PrivilegedActionException' occurred in IKVM.Runtime.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' occurred in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'java.security.PrivilegedActionException' occurred in IKVM.Runtime.dll
>
> A first chance exception of type 'java.io.FileNotFoundException' occurred in IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll

This all making .Net application load very slow, which can be seen manually.
Please suggest what should I do to remove these exception - In short to make my application faster like it was.

Comment: This is what I understand from IKVM discussion forum. But still I am looking for some solution. ---------------------Those aren't errors, but the result of an unfortunate philosophical difference 
between Java and .NET. In Java exceptions are cheap and used for control flow 
pretty often, in .NET they are more expensive and considered exceptional, 
that's why the debugger logs them, even when they are handled (as is the case 
here).

If you run outside of the debugger, you'll see that it is a lot faster.--------